# Calling a stored procedure in Groovy with named parameters

Tags: sql, oracle, grails, stored-procedures, groovy

Suppose I have the following Oracle stored procedure signature:

```
procedure create_user(username_in IN varchar2, another_parameter_name IN varchar2 default 'SOME_DEFAULT_VALUE', password IN varchar2 default 'password', one_more_parameter IN varchar2 default 'ANOTHER_DEFAULT_VALUE');
```

I'm currently issuing a call to the procedure inside Groovy like so:

```
def createUserQuery = "BEGIN create_user(${newUsername}, ${oneParamaterValue}); END;"
sql.execute(createUserQuery)
```

I know that the store procedure signature can change. Therefore, I'd like to specify my non default parameters to the SP by name. Groovy's [Database Features](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Database+features) talks about named parameters for stored procedures as output parameters only.

So what would be the correct way in Groovy to invoke the stored procedure and reference/supply the parameters based on their names? Is there another way to invoke the procedure without writing a `BEGIN; blah blah blah; END;` block?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not ready to answer about Groovy, but your code is based Hibernate. So, you ought to read the Hibernate and your DB docs. All what Hibernate do is preparing query, but the query syntax and capabilities are based on the concrete DB driver.